# Angular CLI Build version has errors. How can I debug?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried running `ng build --dev --bh /home/` as my build command. I put the code on my server and it gives me some errors in the console when you visit the site.

```
TypeError: (void 0) is not a function

TypeError: Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined
```

These errors do not show up when I run the code normally with `ng serve`. My problem is that in the console it just gives some nondescript location for the error: `main.33d3f78f94d41870267a.bundle.js:1` and when I click on it, it brings up the compiled and packed JS code. How can I find out where the issue is?

Comment: Are you checking for a `dirty` variable somewhere in your code? The hard way is to prettify the js in chrome and set a breakpoint where it fails

Comment: Shouldnt I be able to use the .map files? Also Im pretty sure I know the line in TS. But I dont know why its causing and issue after building. It works fine when I use `ng serve`

Comment: @Curtis I also facing this problem. Did you find the answer?